# Can I actually download a file using Gatling script?

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

Can I create a script and can actually download a file to my local disk using gatling?

I tried to create a script to download a file. When I run the script it was successful but looks like the file wasn't actually download. So I was wondering if using gatling a file can actually be downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

Gatling doesn't optimise for this use case.

You can capture the whole byte array in memory using a `bodyBytes` check that you can then save on the filesystem in an `exec(function)`.
But it means you'll retain the whole content in memory at some point, instead of streaming the chunks on the filesystem and discarding them from the memory.